# My computer shut down during a Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ubuntu

After shutting down during a Ubuntu upgrade, I couldn't open my Ubuntu. It first gave me the following image on the screen. I should admit that's a beautiful wallpaper:

[image: Ubuntu crash wallpaper]

But then I turn it off again pressing turn the off button long and after trying to open Ubuntu again, it gave me a black screen this time. So what should I do? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: have you tried to start with ubuntu live cd?

Comment: Nope, I don't have that.

Comment: It _is_ a nice wallpaper :-)

Comment: It looks like a damaged GPU or GPU driver.

Comment: I downloaded this ubuntu inside Windows so can i do something to fix it from Windows?

Comment: Windows does work?

Comment: Yep, it does work. Why this box force me to build long sentence?. It reminds me my elemantary school English teacher.

Comment: During an Ubuntu Upgrade, if a computer shut downs, will it crash?

Comment: Am I right assuming (from what you say) that you installed ubuntu with wubi from windows, because this would make it very hard to fix. Otherwise I'd suggest starting a ubuntu live cd, chrooting into the broken system and trying to finish the upgrade with "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade".

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a CPU or GPU overheating problem. You need to check your laptop for signs of dust on its rear where the fan blows hot air out. If there is a lot of dust here you will need to bring your laptop to service, so they can clean it, and it will not overheat.

Comment: Then why there's no problem in Windows?

Comment: Becouse windows has better hardware drivers and can precisely controls fans in order to prevent overhead. It's a common situation where worse drivers leads to overhead. For example, iMac with MAC OS will work fine even with games, but if you install Windows - it will overhead and hang :).

Comment: Why would that only start happening after a failed upgrade?